# Can void loops run independently?

Tags: c++, arduino

Basically, I have an Arduino Uno R3 hooked up to a 16x2 LCD screen and I want to make 3 different texts appear in the span of 16 seconds on line 0, and on line 1 I would like to add a seconds counter. When starting it the text portion works just fine but the seconds counter only appears after the 16 seconds when all 3 texts have been shown, showing the number 16. When those 3 texts appear once more the counter will now say 32 then 48, 64 so on and forth. So it only shows something after 16 seconds have passed.

What I would like it to do is show every second that has passed (for example 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
    lcd.begin(16, 2); 
}

void loop() {
    text();
    counter();
}

void text() {
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("Text1");
    delay (8000);
  
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("     ");
  
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("Text2");
    delay (4000);
  
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("     ");
  
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("Text3");
    delay (4000);
  
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("     ");
}

void counter() {
    lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
    lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to manually keep track of the time (e.g.: having a variable that stores the result of `millis()`) and use some `if` statements to decide when which part of the code should be executed - in other words, a simple timer

Comment: Instead of `delay`ing for the whole 8 seconds, you'd better use a loop that increases a counter once per second, and when the counter modulo the total time (16 here) equals a certain threshold value (8, 12, 0 in your example) you update the other text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduinos are single core controllers, so you are not able to run multiple loops in parallel without additional tasking features. What you most propably are looking for is called the ***Superloop***. **This is basically an endless loop, containing all tasks of your system.** Tasks are then executed if a timing condition matches.

You can find a lot of introduction and literature to it in the internet and sites like:

- [WikiBooks: Embedded Systems/Super Loop Architecture](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Super_Loop_Architecture)
- [Novos: Super Loop – a Good Approach?](https://www.ee-novos.com/knowledge/superloop/)
- [Microcontrollerslab: Bare-metal and RTOS Based Embedded Systems](https://microcontrollerslab.com/difference-bare-metal-and-rtos-based-embedded-systems/)

You can achieve this in a very simple way like:

```
void loop()
{ 
    //Check if task 1 needs to be executed
    if (millis() - task1LastMillis >= 100) 
    {
        //Get ready for the next iteration
        task1LastMillis = millis();
        myFunction1();
    }
    //Check if task 2 needs to be executed
    if (millis() - task2LastMillis >= 500) 
    {
        //Get ready for the next iteration
        task2LastMillis = millis();
        myFunction2();
    }
    //...
}
```

Note that there are other but more complicated options like using RTOS achieving similar multitasking behaviours.